# Password cannot be Username in CodeIgniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

On registration, I want my 'password' field to have the following custom rule:

`not_matches[username]`

I would then set the following language:

```
$lang['not_matches'] = "The %s field cannot be the same as the %f field";
```

(Assuming `%f` is the field name)

Is this possible?

To be clear, I know how to do `not_matches[".$val."]` but I would like a flexible rule instead.

Comment: `$this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email' );` - %f is the second parameter here. If you want to set a value for you need to pass like this I think in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that i understand what u are saying. You want a rule that says not_matches['username'] being the username another input field?

If so, just go to system\libraries\form_validation.php , then find the matches rule and duplicate it changing the == to !== and the name to not_matches. Then go to system\language\english\form_validation_lang.php and create the message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such support yet in CI. You need to write your own callback validation routine.

There is an example that can be easily adapted to your needs in the [CI manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.

#### application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php

```
$this_lang = basename(__DIR__);
require_once("./system/language/$this_lang/form_validation_lang.php");

$lang['not_match'] = "The %s field must not match the %s field.";
```

#### application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function not_match($str, $field)
  {
    if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $field = $_POST[$field];

    return ($str === $field) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }

}
```

Then the rule is simply `not_match[field_name]`